# Can't make ImageView visible when ACTION_DRAG_ENDED is fired

Tags: android, gridview, drag-and-drop, visibility

I have an ImageView and a GridView. When I start to drag the image, i make it invisible (GONE):

```
imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence) view.getTag());
                String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};
                ClipData dragData = new ClipData(view.getTag().toString(), mimeTypes, item);

                View.DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(imageView);

                view.startDrag(dragData, myShadow, piece, 0);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Now the view that I drop matches one view on the GridView. If I drop it on it, I don't need nothing to happen, and if I drop it on any other view I make it visible again and that works fine (all this happens inside the GridView Adapter).

BUT, I also want to make it visible if it wan't dropped on the GridView at all (for example, it was dropped on the empty space between the GridView and the original View).
I tried this:

```
imageView.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent dragEvent) {
                int action = dragEvent.getAction();
                switch (action) {
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                            Log.d("test", "visible");
                            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

I see the log message so the ACTION_DRAG_ENDED is fired, but the imageView's visibility doesn't change. Any ideas anyone?